# Gatling JDBC with dynamic where clause

Tags: gatling, scala-gatling

I'm using Gatling with the JDBC feeder and would like to dynamically add a parameter to the JDBC feeder's where clause based on the response from a previous request. Here is my example, I'm trying to do a post that will create a user, then have the feed grab the user's generated UUID using the userId returned from the create user request, then post some data with the UUID.

```
val dbConnectionString = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/user"
val sqlQuery = "SELECT user_uuid FROM users where user_id = '${userId}'"
val sqlUserName = "dbUser"
val sqlPassword = "dbPassword"
val sqlQueryFeeder = jdbcFeeder(dbConnectionString, sqlUserName, sqlPassword, sqlQuery)
val uuidPayload = """{"userUUID":"${user_uuid}"}"""

val MyScenario = scenario("MyScenario").exec(
(pause(1, 2))
.exec(http("SubmitFormThatCreatesUserData")
  .post(USER_CREATE_URL)
  .body(StringBody("""{"username":"test@test.com"}""")).asJson
  .header("Accept", "application/json")
  .check(status.is(200))
  .check(jsonPath("$..data.userId").exists.saveAs("userId")))
.feed(sqlQueryFeeder) 
.exec(http("SubmitStuffWithUUID")
  .post(myUUIDPostURL)
  .body(uuidPayload).asJson
  .header("Accept", "application/json")
  .check(status.is(200)))
)
```

I have verified the following:

1) The user data does get inserted into the DB correctly on the form post
2) The userId is returned from that form post 
3) The userId correctly saved as a Gatling session variable 
4) The SQL query will execute correctly if I hard-code the user id variable

The problem I have is that when I have the Gatling `${userId}` parameter on the JDBC feeder's where clause it appears the `userId` variable isn't used, I get an error saying `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Feeder must not be empty`. When I replace the `${userId}` with a hard-coded userId everything works as expected. I would just like to know how I can use the `userId` session parameter in my JDBC feeder's where clause.

Answer (score 0):

The call to `jdbcFeeder(dbConnectionString, sqlUserName, sqlPassword, sqlQuery)` to create a jdbc feeder only takes strings as parameters, not gatling expressions (like ${userId}).

In your scenario as posted, you are not really using feeders as intended - they are generally used to have different users pick up different values from a pool of values whereas you have a static user name and are only taking the first value returned from the db. It's generally not a good idea to have fetching of external data in the middle of your scenarios as it can make timings unpredictable.

Could you just look up and hardcode the user_uuid? The best approach would be to get all your user data and look up things like uuids in the `before` block of the simulation. However, you can't use the gatling DSL there.

You could also use a scala variable to store the user_uuid and define a feeder inline, but this would get messy if you do need to support multiple users

Comment: Thanks James, that makes sense. My issue is that my scenario calls one rest service that creates data and then another that needs to use that data. I changed the scenario a bit because I didn't want to expose any client specifics. Basically, users register for an account and are sent a verification code in an email.  I want to read the verification code from the database so I can simulate the user entering the code they got in their email. Is my best option to register a bunch of users in one scenario, then submit their verification codes in another scenario?

Comment: Yep - exactly as you suggest, user creation and login are separate simulations.